# android customer complains with download error Licensed

Tags: android, runtime-error

We are fairly new to the GooglePlay store and seemed to figure out everything just fine. I occasionally will get emails from customers saying that they can not open the app and they got the error "Licensed". No code numbers or anything. Just "Licensed". And here is the weird part some people can download apps fine and dandy and open them just fine. Also everything looks fine from my end so I don't really know where to start. From what I can find most of the troubleshooting seemed to be uninstalling and reinstalling and rebooting the app and device.

If anyone knows how to fix it I would appreciate it. Or just let me know if its a customer device issue or a developer/app issue. It's hard giving out refunds when I can see all the downloads and only some seem to have this issue.

Help. =)

Answer (score 0):

That really is not a lot of information to go on, but is it possible the developers added this 'licensed' dialog for debugging/testing purposes and forgot to remove it from the production build?

Comment: Is that under the developer profile where License Test Response is?

Comment: sorry, we are fairly experienced with Apple but have zero to negative experience in android and are having some trouble learning it since none of our developers have ever learned it or used it.